# Lion and Unicorn with Prolog SAT Solver

Tags: prolog, sat

Would a Prolog SAT solver have an advantage in solving this riddle:

> When Alice entered the forest of forgetfulness, she did not
> forget everything, only certain things. She often forgot her
> name, and the most likely thing for her to forget was the day
> of the week. Now, the lion and the unicorn were frequent
> visitors to this forest. These two are strange creatures. The
> lion lies on Mondays, Tuesdays, and Wednesdays and tells
> the truth on the other days of the week. The unicorn, on the
> other hand, lies on Thursdays, Fridays, and Saturdays, but tells
> the truth on the other days of the week.
>
> One day Alice met the lion and the unicorn resting under a tree.
> They made the following statements:
>
> Lion: Yesterday was one of my lying days.
> Unicorn: Yesterday was one of my lying days.
>
> From these statements, Alice, who was a bright girl, was able to
> deduce the day of the week. What was it?

Performance advantage over a solution like here (Free Access):

**The lion and the unicorn met PROLOG**
Bruce Ramsey - 1986
https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/382278.382395

Comment: Performance questions often defy simple intuition. If you want to be sure, measure.

Comment: But my intuition suggests that the linked solution is very concise and will do very few operations and you will struggle to match it with a more general tool like a SAT solver.

Answer (score 1):

Preventing execution of `yesterday_today` twice:

```
lying_day(lion, mon).
lying_day(lion, tue).
lying_day(lion, wed).

lying_day(unicorn, thu).
lying_day(unicorn, fri).
lying_day(unicorn, sat).

yesterday_today(mon, tue).
yesterday_today(tue, wed).
yesterday_today(wed, thu).
yesterday_today(thu, fri).
yesterday_today(fri, sat).
yesterday_today(sat, sun).
yesterday_today(sun, mon).

lion_unicorn(Today) :-
    animal_consistent_day(lion, Yesterday, Today),
    % Don't call yesterday_today again, for performance
    animal_consistent(unicorn, Yesterday, Today).

animal_consistent_day(Animal, Yesterday, Today) :-
    % Delay yesterday_today, for performance
    lying_day(Animal, Yesterday),
    yesterday_today(Yesterday, Today),
    % Telling truth
    \+ lying_day(Animal, Today).
animal_consistent_day(Animal, Yesterday, Today) :-
    % Lying
    lying_day(Animal, Today),
    yesterday_today(Yesterday, Today),
    \+ lying_day(Animal, Yesterday).

animal_consistent(Animal, Yesterday, Today) :-
    lying_day(Animal, Yesterday),
    % Telling truth
    \+ lying_day(Animal, Today).
animal_consistent(Animal, Yesterday, Today) :-
    % Lying
    lying_day(Animal, Today),
    \+ lying_day(Animal, Yesterday).
```

Results in swi-prolog:

```
?- time(lion_unicorn(D)).
% 14 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (71% CPU, 1219406 Lips)
D = thu ;
% 16 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (91% CPU, 1453224 Lips)
false.
```

```
?- time((between(1, 1000000, _), lion_unicorn(_), fail; true)).
% 27,000,001 inferences, 1.314 CPU in 1.316 seconds (100% CPU, 20540412 Lips)
```

Comment: Cool, yesterday/2 is bidirectionally used!

Comment: Oops, added missing `yesterday_today(sun, mon).` Decreased elegance, to scrape the barrel of performance :-)

Answer (score 1):

Preventing a separate lookup for `yesterday_today`:

```
lying_day(lion, mon, tue).
lying_day(lion, tue, wed).
lying_day(lion, wed, thu).

lying_day(unicorn, thu, fri).
lying_day(unicorn, fri, sat).
lying_day(unicorn, sat, sun).

lion_unicorn(Today) :-
    animal_consistent(lion, Yesterday, Today),
    animal_consistent(unicorn, Yesterday, Today).

animal_consistent(Animal, Yesterday, Today) :-
    lying_day(Animal, Yesterday, Today),
    % Telling truth
    \+ lying_day(Animal, Today, _).
animal_consistent(Animal, Yesterday, Today) :-
    % Lying
    lying_day(Animal, Today, _),
    \+ lying_day(Animal, Yesterday, Today).
```

Results in swi-prolog:

```
?- time(lion_unicorn(D)).
% 11 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (85% CPU, 1104529 Lips)
D = thu ;
% 13 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (91% CPU, 1176364 Lips)
false.
```

```
?- time((between(1, 1000000, _), lion_unicorn(_), fail; true)).
% 21,000,001 inferences, 1.183 CPU in 1.184 seconds (100% CPU, 17755003 Lips)
```

Comment: Can learn again something! More enjoyable than what ChatGPT & Co. supposedly produced. LoL

Answer (score 0):

For example one can use four facts `and(0,0,0)`, `and(0,1,1)`, `and(1,0,1)` and `and(1,1,1)` to find solution to propositional conjunctions. A SAT solver is a computer program which aims to solve the Boolean
satisfiability problem.

Here is a first SAT solving like solution. Unlike other posts,
which assume that SAT means `library(clpb)`, I don't assume that. Maybe the below sketch is a starting point for nevertheless some SAT solution that gives it an itch of additional speed?

```
yesterday(0,0,0,1,1,0).
yesterday(0,0,1,0,0,0).
yesterday(0,1,0,0,0,1).
yesterday(0,1,1,0,1,0).
yesterday(1,0,0,0,1,1).
yesterday(1,0,1,1,0,0).
yesterday(1,1,0,1,0,1).

lying_day(0,0,0,1).
lying_day(0,0,1,0).
lying_day(0,0,1,1).
lying_day(1,1,0,0).
lying_day(1,1,0,1).
lying_day(1,1,1,0).

solve_for(T1,T2,T3) :- yesterday(T1,T2,T3,Y1,Y2,Y3)
, contrary(lying_day(0,T1,T2,T3), lying_day(0,Y1,Y2,Y3))
, contrary(lying_day(1,T1,T2,T3), lying_day(1,Y1,Y2,Y3)).

contrary(S,T) :- \+ S, T.
contrary(S,T) :- S, \+ T.
```

Also unlike other posts that claim SAT is automatically
expensive, since they assume its `library(clpb)`, I only
see so far that it has same speed with Bruce Ramseys solution:

```
?- time(solve_for(T1,T2,T3)).
% 32 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (0% CPU, Infinite Lips)
T1 = 1,
T2 = T3, T3 = 0 ;
% 17 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (0% CPU, Infinite Lips)
false.

?- time((between(1,1000000,_), solve_for(T1,T2,T3), fail; true)).
% 46,000,000 inferences, 3.813 CPU in 3.802 seconds (100% CPU, 12065574 Lips)
true.
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was using a SAT solver in a little unorthodox way.
Used it as a compiler for a formula, so that I got:

```
yesterday(0,0,0,1,1,0).
yesterday(0,0,1,0,0,0).
yesterday(0,1,0,0,0,1).
yesterday(0,1,1,0,1,0).
yesterday(1,0,0,0,1,1).
yesterday(1,0,1,1,0,0).
yesterday(1,1,0,1,0,1).

two_liars(T1,T2,T3,Y1,Y2,Y3) :-
   T1=\=Y1,
   T1=:=(T1/\Y2) xor (T1/\Y3) xor (Y2/\Y3),
   Y1=:=(T2/\T3) xor (T2/\Y1) xor (T3/\Y1),
   T1=\=(T1/\T2) xor (T1/\T3) xor T2 xor (T2/\T3) xor T3,
   Y1=\=(Y1/\Y2) xor (Y1/\Y3) xor Y2 xor (Y2/\Y3) xor Y3.

solve_for(T1,T2,T3) :-
   yesterday(T1,T2,T3,Y1,Y2,Y3),
   two_liars(T1,T2,T3,Y1,Y2,Y3).
```

Works fine and is fast with `optimise=true`:

```
/* SWI-Prolog 9.1.17, optimise=false */
?- time(solve_for(T1,T2,T3)).
% 16 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (0% CPU, Infinite Lips)
T1 = 1,
T2 = T3, T3 = 0 ;
% 10 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (0% CPU, Infinite Lips)
false.

/* SWI-Prolog 9.1.17, optimise=true */
?- time((between(1, 1000000, _), solve_for(T1,T2,T3), fail; true)).
% 9,999,999 inferences, 1.203 CPU in 1.199 seconds
(100% CPU, 8311687 Lips)
```

**Edit 14.11.2023**
So how to use a SAT solver as a compiler. First model
the problem with `library(clpb)` as Boolean formulas.

```
lying_day(A, B, C, D, M) :- M = (
   ~A* ~B* ~C*D+
   ~A* ~B*C* ~D+
   ~A* ~B*C*D+
   A*B* ~C* ~D+
   A*B* ~C*D+
   A*B*C* ~D).

two_liars(T1, T2, T3, Y1, Y2, Y3, ((M1#M2)*(M3#M4))) :-
    lying_day(0, T1, T2, T3, M1),
    lying_day(0, Y1, Y2, Y3, M2),
    lying_day(1, T1, T2, T3, M3),
    lying_day(1, Y1, Y2, Y3, M4).
```

Then look at the normalform:

```
?- two_liars(T1,T2,T3,Y1,Y2,Y3,M), sat(M).
sat(1#T2*T3#T2*Y1#T3*Y1#Y1),
sat(T1=:=T1*Y2#T1*Y3#Y2*Y3),
sat(T1=\=Y1),
sat(T1=\=T1*T2#T1*T3#T2#T2*T3#T3),
sat(Y1=\=Y1*Y2#Y1*Y3#Y2#Y2*Y3#Y3).
```

Take the normalform, reorder the equations a little bit, fewer
variables first, and rewrite them into ISO core standard bitwise
operations, and then take profit.